# Git Permissions Issue

Tags: permissions, git

I'm having some kind of git permissions issue and i'm hoping somebody can help. Every time I try to commit I get the following:

```
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects
error: Error building trees
```

I've looked at several suggestions for resolving this and they basically boil to make sure non of your permissions are broken in the .git folder. I've confirmed that I have permissions for everything. I also checked the output of `git config core.sharedRepository` is `true`.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does this happen while working on your local machine? Does it happen when you push to a remote? Do you share it with others? Are you using the same local git repo with multiple accounts?

Comment: I am on my local machine trying to make a commit.

I only use one account with the same local repo

Answer (score 3):

You somehow either messed the permissions or the owner or group up. The latter both should be your user or your user's group respectively.

Open a terminal in your repo or navigate into it. Then execute these commands:

```
sudo chown -R david .git
sudo chgrp -R david .git
```

This will make you the owner and your group the group of all the files in the `.git` folder. Assuming your username is `david`, of course. If it isn't, change it. Your group has the same name as your user. If you want to apply this to your entire repo, just replace `.git` by `.` (a single period).

If this doesn't fix the problem, execute these lines:

```
find .git -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +
find .git -type f -exec chmod 644 {} +
```

The first line gives you full permissions for all directories and the second one the permissions to read from and to write to files in `.git` folder. The first line may print errors, informing you – once more – about insufficient permissions because `find` can't walk into folders before their permissions have been set properly (if they are set entirely wrong). If this happens, run the first command again (before running the second command) until it doesn't print errors any more. You can of course avoid this by running the first command as `root` (`sudo find .git -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +`). Then, it'll run through without errors the first time in any case.

The second command makes all files in the `.git` folder non-executable. This isn't a problem of you don't use hooks. If you do, you probably want to execute

```
chmod +x .git/hooks/*
```

afterwards to give the hooks the execute bits back. If you don't give them those back, your hooks won't be executed any more. Doing this if you don't use hooks does no harm.

Comment: Hmm. The second command should be (at least for `u`) `u+rwX`, so that executable scripts, if any, in the folder retain their executable state.

Comment: The commands only change the permissions of the `.git` folder and its contents, not the files OP works with. Hooks should be the only executable files in the `.git`and OP probably doesn't use any. Whether the sample hooks are executable or not doesn't matter as they aren't executed anyways. Using `u+rwX` would leave accidentally set executable bits on files as they are.

Comment: ah, but we don't post answers only for the sake of the OP. The warning will be useful for future visitors.